# How to get distant server free space

Tags: bash, ssh, automation

Hi I am currently trying to automate file transfer to a distant server using bash commands but I want to be able to know how much space is left on that server before I attempt to send multiple files.

For instance if the server has 5GB left I want to send 4.5GB. This is the code I came up with (form multiple other type of questions) but I cant use this data to automate the process

```
spaceLeft=`ssh -i /cygdrive/C/cygwin64/home/turco/IDs/fileTransfer -p 2222 root@localhost " df -h /var/mobile"`
echo $spaceLeft
IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< "$spaceLeft"
for index in "${!array[@]}"
do
    echo "$index ${array[index]}"
done
```

when I echo spaceleft this appears

```
Filesystem     Size Used Avail Capacity iused  ifree     %iused Mounted on 
/dev/disk0s1s2 60Gi 45Gi 6.9Gi 87%      318900 624035540 0%     /private/var
```

when I echo all items in the array this appears

```
0 Filesystem
1 Size
2 Used
3 Avail
4 Capacity
5 iused
6 ifree
7 %iused
8 Mounted
9 on
```

All I want to know is the 6.9Gi space left but I cant find a way to get it

Comment: Which OS and version of `df` do you use?

Comment: The server in question is my jailbroken iPhone on IOS 14.3 and is using the OpenSSH tweak as for the df version ... I cant say. On my computer I am using cygwin

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if the server has 5TB, 5MB or 5kB left, how much are you supposed to send then?

Comment: I want to send files if space left after transfer is more than 500MB. I'll code it later

Comment: So you need a translation from `PiB`, `TiB`, `MiB` etc...?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest with GNU `df`:

```
df -hP /var/mobile | awk 'NR==2{print $4}'
```

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, **NR**, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: how can I show more decimal like 6.905GB or 6.91GB.  also I found this for file sizing which uses the same awk option and provides how many decimals I want. [Code](https://serverfault.com/a/859005)
How could I edit it to be useful ?

Comment: I don't know your `df`'s features/options. What does your `df` output if you remove `-h` and `-P` from my answer?

Comment: when I put -hP this happens `Space left : 4104440` and when I put -h this happens `Space left : 2.0Gi`

Comment: Okay, use `-hP` and replace `print $4` with `printf("%.3fGi\n", $4*512/1024/1024/1024)`, e.g., to get `1.957Gi`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want what's left on one drive you could `tail -1` to skip the heading and then print the fourth field.

I also suggest that you set the blocksize to the smallest unit you want to handle and not use the `-h` (human readable) format.

```
gigsleft=$(ssh ... df -B 1G /var/mobile | tail -1 | awk '{ print $4 }')
```

`gigsleft` should now contain the number of gigs left, without a unit - so you don't need to parse it. If you want the space left in megs, use `-B 1M` instead.

If you want it in gibibytes *with decimals*, use the same approach using `df -B` and select a smaller unit, like `k`, and divide it down:

```
df -B 1k /var/mobile | tail -1 | awk '{ printf("%.3f\n", $4/1024^2); }'
```

Using decimals for this doesn't seem to make much sense though. You are using the number to fill up a certain percentage or amount of the disk so I suggest that you request a smaller unit from `df`, like `k`, or even `df -B 1`

```
df -B 1 /var/mobile | tail -1 | awk '{ print $4 }'
```

...to get the number of free bytes, and use that as your smallest unit throughout the script.